# Check if migration needed

Tags: go, go-gorm

My microservice uses gorm and deploy into kubernetes cluster with several instances. So when new version of app deployed several tasks with auto migration starts in parallel.

I want to start one app witch starts migration and when it will be finished then several examples of main app will starts.

How can I check in my application if database need migration, so my app can exit after check if migration does not completed?

Comment: If you really need this _auto_-migration, then you need to store some value you may call "schema version" somewhere in your database. This value is only changed when the DB has finished migrating to a new schema. A particular build of the app checks that version value early at its startup as it "knows" (usualy via some `const` in its source code) the schema version it is able to work with, and exits if the version is not the one expected.

Comment: Actually this will be a bad architecture the flow should be e.g you have CI/CD it will deploy e.g if it's docker then in ecs or some other docker registry & will run command for migration from CLI it will be disaster if you run migration in every service of your kubernetes

Comment: @kostix thanks. Is there some existing api for version check in gorm, or i must do it mannualy?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA in common approach migrations starts in special job in kubernetes deployment before main pods start. If this job fails then main pods not start.